# Best practice for syncing private keys between server instances

Tags: rest, security, session, encryption, jwt

I'm working on a project that uses jwt (json web tokens) to check whether a user is authenticated with the system.

The services are completely stateless, so I can easily scale from one instance to a few dozens. There is only one issue. To be able to validate the jwt on every instance, I need to synchronize the symmetric secret key between the instances.

Of course I could build a system that uses some sort of service discovery and exchanges the symmetric key by encrypting it with an asymmetrical encryption. This just doesn't feel like a proper method.
I could set a fixed key on every instance but changing the key, which effectively invalidates all the previously created tokens, would be a pain.
I don't want to set a master instante every other instance is relying on.

My third idea was using an asymmetrical approach and letting each instance create their own key pair. By writing the issuer in the token, the instance that gets called could retrieve the public key from the instance that issued the token and validate the token this way.

It's not like I don't have any ideas. I just don't really like my ideas so far.

Do you have any best practices to solve such a problem?

Comment: Could you have a central authentication service to issue all your tokens?Then you could have a single asymmetric, private / public key pair and you would only need to distribute the public key between the servers to validate your tokens. Distributing the public key does not require security measures

Comment: Theoretically, yes and I thought about doing that. The reason I don't want to have single centralized point for doing the authentication is, that this would result in a single point of failure of the system. Of course I could deploy several instances of the authentication service but that would result in the same problem and the creation of very small services. If I have the authentication service included in each instance I don't have to deploy and scale different services.

Comment: You have summarized the options 1)Share the key 2) unique authentication server 3) publish the public key of each authentication server and trust in it. You said that you are authenticating users, I assume you have a central infrastructure/database to manage them, then, why do not you use it to share the key?

Comment: Good point. If each instance is capable of authorizing users, it has to be able to access this database anyway. I think that's the way to go.